# Google Map API V3.0 - How to Detect MapTypeId Change

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

To add a listener to detect a zoom change works with the following:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'zoom_changed',function())
```

What is the code to detect a change in the map type from `ROADMAP` to another view like 
`SATELLITE`? I can get the value:

```
val myMapType = map.getMapTypeId();
```

but do not know how to detect the change in view.

*I am using the Google Map API V3.0*

Answer (score 21):

OK worked it out:

```
google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'maptypeid_changed', function() { 
    document.getElementById( "maptype" ).value = map.getMapTypeId();
} );
```

Comment: The returns of getMapTypeID are either "roadmap" "satellite" or "hybrid" -- often hybrid gets triggered for satellite even when the user clicks on the satellite tab